# Ошибка Component not initialized

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

помогите пожалуйста победить консольную ошибку

на страничке
http://prozaik.16mb.com/js2/search_mysql_XHR_get_without_params/
 выполняю ajax-запрос. первый раз он отрабатывает нормально(выводит текст на экран). второй раз не нормально(в консоли выводится сообщение об ошибке: NS_ERROR_NOT_INITIALIZED: Component not initialized)

вот код search.php:

```
echo('privet <br /> hello');
```

js:

```
            function getXmlHttp(){
          var xmlhttp;
          try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (e) {
            try {
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (E) {
              xmlhttp = false;
            }
          }
          if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest!='undefined') {
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
          return xmlhttp;
        }

        var xmlhttp = getXmlHttp();

        xmlhttp.open('GET', 'search.php', true);

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
                }
            }
        };

        $('#btn_search').on('click', function(event){
            var data;

            event = event || window.event;
            event.preventDefault();

            xmlhttp.send(null);     
        });
```

Comment: Нужно сделать open еще раз, а почему Вы сначала пытаетесь создать микрософтовские объекты?  Лучше первым делом пытаться создать XMLHttpRequest, примените лучше кроссбраузерную инициализацию из [вики](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest)

Comment: скажите пожалуйста что значит
>Нужно сделать open еще раз
я не понял

Comment: Вероятно, что Вы используете для тестов IE, который освобождает объект после успешного окончания запроса. Для повторного использования нужно снова сделать open и соответственно send.  
Когда Вы второй раз кликаете по кнопке делается еще раз send без open.

Comment: А зачем, при использовании jquery использовать объекты типа XMLHttpRequest и ActiveXObject ?

Comment: @Чад, ТС переписывает на чистый js что-то, проблема с производительностью.

Comment: Не думаю что кусок $.ajax такой тормоз чтобы его переписывать

Comment: после продолжительной писанины на jq я решил поизучать js. все последние мои вопросы на этом сайте в подобном ключе